# Why did Veronica Mars series end in the 3rd season?

Tags: veronica-mars

Why did Veronica Mars series end in the 3rd season? I found the plot of the whole series really nice and interesting. I'm gonna see the movie in the next few days but it seems unfair to end like this...not knowing what happens between Piz and her, how Vinnie Van Lowe is elected sheriff, how her dad clears his name or continues his life, what she does as an intern in FBI...

Comment: Duncan Kane ... He used to be my boyfriend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of low rating, it got critical acclaim but it lacked in attracting more viewers. So it got cancelled after 3rd season by The CW.

> A group of fans calling themselves the "Cloud Watchers" sent more
>   than 10,000 Mars bars to the CW, hoping that the network would reverse
>   its decision and renew the series. (Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronica_Mars_%28season_3%29#Cancellation_and_future))

The movie was made only to give closers to the unanswered questions. Even Warner Bros. said no to produce the film, it was [Kickstarter fund-raising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronica_Mars_%28film%29#Development) which made it possible.

[Here](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/style-blog/wp/2014/03/13/veronica-mars-creator-rob-thomas-explains-how-his-canceled-show-rose-from-the-ashes-for-a-groundbreaking-movie/) is the creator's word on the whole story.

Note: So if you want to complete the story you need to watch the movie after the 3rd season.

**Edit-**

As  BCdotNET said there is a [Season 4 teaser](http://veronicamars.wikia.com/wiki/Veronica_in_the_FBI) made for an attempt of making season 4 but this teaser is became non-canonical because of movie’s story conflicting with it.

Comment: What is *"TRP"*, though (some kind of viewer ratings I guess)?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yup, in India we use this word so often. I will change the word.

Comment: Don't forget about the 12 minute ["Veronica in the FBI" teaser](http://veronicamars.wikia.com/wiki/Veronica_in_the_FBI).

Comment: @BCdotNET its non canonical now after movie.